# Search On Custom Query Result-Collection With Algolia - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, search, algolia

I have collection that created with complicated laravel query and this query's result is too big. So i think i must use algolia. As i know, algolia gets the model table data to itself as `json` and serve from there.

```
$result = User::search("UserName")->get();
```

It needs to some model configurations like `searchAs` etc.. all are related with existing model and you can make search from model with `search` method (above example). What i want to ask is, i have complicated query and result has too many attributes that come from another tables (joined). I want to make search on my custom query result. Is it possible ?

**My example query :**

```
    $friendShips = Friend::
    join("vp_users as users","users.id","=","friendships.friendID")
        ->leftJoin("vp_friendships as friendshipsForFriend",function($join) use ($request)
        {
            $join->on("friendships.friendID","=","friendshipsForFriend.userID");
            $join->on("friendshipsForFriend.friendID","=",DB::raw($request->userID));

        })
        ->leftJoin("vp_videos_friends as videosFromFriendMedias",function($join)
        {
            $join->on("videosFromFriendMedias.userID","=","friendships.friendID");
            $join->on("videosFromFriendMedias.friendID", "=" ,"friendships.userID");
            $join->on("videosFromFriendMedias.isCalled", "=" , DB::raw(self::CALLED));

        })
        ->leftJoin("vp_videos_friends as videosToFriendMedias",function($join)
        {
            $join->on("videosToFriendMedias.userID", '=', "friendships.userID");
            $join->on("videosToFriendMedias.friendID", '=', "friendships.friendID");
            $join->on(function($join){
                $join->on("videosToFriendMedias.isCalled", '=', DB::raw(self::CALLED));
                $join->orOn("videosToFriendMedias.isActive", '=', DB::raw(self::ACTIVE));
            });
        })
        ->leftJoin("vp_videos_friends as 
        //some join rules too
        })...
```

Comment: Are you indexing the Friend model and you want to create a separate index for this query?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way would be to use this request and chain the `searchable()` method. It will index the collection returned by the query to Algolia.

```
$friendShips = Friend::
    join("vp_users as users","users.id","=","friendships.friendID")
    ->leftJoin("vp_friendships as friendshipsForFriend",function($join) use ($request) {
        $join->on("friendships.friendID","=","friendshipsForFriend.userID");
        $join->on("friendshipsForFriend.friendID","=",DB::raw($request->userID));

    })
    ->searchable();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i will get back to you when i try and succeeded.

Comment: Don't hesitate to mark my answer if that worked for you ;)